# How can i integrate Zoom.us into my angularJS app?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sdk

Recently, I am working on zoom.us and I want to integrate Zoom.us into my angular app, Is there any way to integrate Zoom.us or SDK? (Not API's), I have tried with javascript but is not working.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue by using javascript API's, zoom does not provide any plugin or dependency for angular js.

[javascript apis](https://zoom.us/developer/overview/getting-started-with-javascript-api)

Comment: Can You please provide more details on  Javascript APIs.

Comment: I think the link was not working as zoom has changed its documentations. for more details please follow the link for javascript https://marketplace.zoom.us/docs/guides/zoom-sdks/Web-Client-SDK , and for example follow the https://github.com/zoom/sample-app-web/blob/master/js/index.js link

Comment: I checked sample-app-web GitHub project, But this project requires  react.js.

Comment: This is the plain javascript, You can use this js in any client side js. React js is not necessary You have to do some modification on js so it will compatible with your frontend.

Comment: or you can use APIs if client side SDK is not compatible with your source code.https://marketplace.zoom.us/docs/api-reference/master-account-apis/user-apis

Comment: I Think,  You didn't check the library properly, Sample app web dependent on react.js. More info please check the https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/community/posts/360032387532-How-to-integrate-Zoom-Web-Client-to-Angular-5